# Objective c/cocoa web view loading when typing string url but not when passing NSString*

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, webview, nsstring

In my DetailViewController.h file, I have declared a NSString * property:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *url;
```

In my DetailViewController.m file, I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

This loads google.com in my web view but the following code does not:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *url = self.url;
    NSLog(@"this is url %@", url);
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Which prints out: "this is url http://google.com".

Both url and @"http://google.com" are NSString* objects but why is the first coding loading the website but the second is not?

Comment: My guess is that self.url is changed or otherwise become invalid right after your call, but before the request can be loaded.

Try changing the 3rd line to:
`NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString:self.url];

Comment: @RehcsifMit thanks, realized had whitespace at the end of the url.

Comment: I don't understand how the first segment works (or even compiles) with a C string parm to `URLWithString:`.

Comment: @HotLicks, it was just a typo. yes, i need to add a "@" in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So realized there was whitespace at the end of url that I hadn't noticed until I printed out:

```
NSLog(@"this is url %@.", url);
```

Notice the period I added in the end. I had whitespace there, hence rendering my url invalid. I had to trim out the whitespace somewhere else in my code.